# How to correctly terminate a Thread with Indy HTTP Get command inside?

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, indy, indy10

My app make a `GET` command on a `FormShow` event, sometimes the user may press `Back` and close the Form after the Thread is started and has not finished yet, leading to errors like `Thread Error: Invalid argument (22)` or `Thread Error: No such process (3)`.

```
procedure TForm58.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if Assigned(LListThread) then LListThread := nil;
    LListThread := TLoadListThread.Create;
    LListThread.OnTerminate := LoadListThreadTerminated;
    LListThread.Start;
end;

constructor TLoadListThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.Execute;
begin
    if Form58.IdHTTP1.Connected then Form58.IdHTTP1.Disconnect;
    st := TStringList.Create;
    try
        ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
        Synchronize(
        procedure
        begin
            Form58.Label1.Text := 'Loading...';
        end);
        try
            Form58.IdHTTP1.Get(urlserver,ms);
            ms.Position := 0;
            st.LoadFromStream(ms, TEncoding.UTF8);
        finally
            ms.Free;
        end;
        // Do something with st
    finally
        st.Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm58.LoadListThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if IdHTTP1.Tag = 1 then
    begin
        LListThread := nil;
        Form58.Close;
    end else
    begin
      LListThread := nil;
      if TThread(Sender).FatalException = nil then
      // Do something
      else
      // Do otherthing
    end;
end;

procedure TForm58.CloseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(LListThread) then
  begin
    IdHTTP1.Tag := 1;
    LListThread.Terminate;
  end else Form58.Close;
end;

procedure TForm58.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if Assigned(LListThread) then
  begin
    LListThread.Destroy;
    LListThread := nil;
  end;
  try
    // Do something
  finally
    Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
  end;
end;
```

I know this Thread start/end logic I made is crappy, how can I improve it and remove the error messages from being displayed?

Comment: Try a different strategy: don't allow the form to close until the get has finished.

Comment: Use a thread-safe strategy: create and use the TIdHTTP only within the Execute method

Comment: You should *seriously* consider the following practice: Write your thread in a unit of its own which does *not* use any form unit, or any VCL unit at all for that matter. VCL is not thread-safe. Directly accessing your form from within a thread is beyond crappy - it is not logical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When getting ready to close the Form, if the thread is still running then you are signaling it to terminate, but you don't wait for it to fully terminate, and then you explicitly destroy the thread object when the form actually closes, even though you are using `FreeOnTerminate=True`.

You should be calling `TThread.WaitFor()` before explicitly destroying a thread object, but that doesn't work when using `FreeOnTerminate=True`, which causes the kind of errors you are seeing.  In addition to that, the `TThread` destructor calls `WaitFor()` on itself if the thread is still running, and you are explicitly destroying the thread object.  So either way, you are causing errors.

So, you need to either:

- set `FreeOnTerminate=False`, and then wait for the thread to fully terminate before explicitly destroying it.
- set `FreeOnTerminate=True` and don't destroy the thread object manually at all, and don't close the Form until the thread is terminated.

I would also suggest overriding the thread's virtual `TerminatedSet()` method to set a flag that can then be checked inside the thread to abort the `GET` request, such as in the `TIdHTTP.OnWork` events.

Try something like this, when using `FreeOnTerminated=True`:

```
type
  TLoadListThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FUrl: string;
    FOnLoading: TNotifyEvent;
    DoAbort: Boolean;
    procedure CheckAbort;
    procedure DoLoading;
    procedure HTTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
  protected
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const AUrl: String);
    property OnLoading: TNotifyEvent read FOnLoading write FOnLoading;
  end;

constructor TLoadListThread.Create(const AUrl: String);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FUrl := AUrl;
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.CheckAbort;
begin
  if DoAbort then SysUtils.Abort;
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.DoLoading;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnLoading) then FOnLoading(Self);
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.HTTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
  CheckAbort;
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  inherited;
  DoAbort := True;
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.Execute;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    st := TStringList.Create;
    try
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        if Assigned(FOnLoading) then Synchronize(DoLoading);
        CheckAbort;
        HTTP.Get(FUrl, ms);
        ms.Position := 0;
        st.LoadFromStream(ms, TEncoding.UTF8);
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
      CheckAbort;
      // Do something with st
    finally
      st.Free;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
private
  procedure CloseOnTerminated(Sender: TObject);

procedure TForm58.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StopLoadListThread;
  LListThread := TLoadListThread.Create(urlserver);
  LListThread.OnLoading := LoadListThreadLoading;
  LListThread.OnTerminate := LoadListThreadFinished;
  LListThread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm58.StopLoadListThread;
begin
  if Assigned(LListThread) then
  begin
    LListThread.OnLoading := nil;
    LListThread.OnTerminate := nil;
    LListThread.Terminate;
    LListThread := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm58.LoadListThreadLoading(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Text := 'Loading...';
end;

procedure TForm58.LoadListThreadFinished(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if LListThread.FatalException = nil then
    // Do something
  else
    // Do something else

  LListThread := nil;
end;

procedure TForm58.CloseOnTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LListThread := nil;
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm58.CloseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm58.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if Assigned(LListThread) then
  begin
    LListThread.OnTerminate := CloseOnTerminated;
    LListThread.Terminate;
    Action := TCloseAction.caNone;
  end
  else
  begin
    // Do something
    Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
  end;
end;
```

Or this, when using `FreeOnTerminated=False`:

```
type
  TLoadListThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FUrl: string;
    FOnLoading: TNotifyEvent;
    DoAbort: Boolean;
    procedure CheckAbort;
    procedure DoLoading;
    procedure HTTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
  protected
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const AUrl: String);
    property OnLoading: TNotifyEvent read FOnLoading write FOnLoading;
  end;

constructor TLoadListThread.Create(const AUrl: String);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := False;
  FUrl := AUrl;
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.CheckAbort;
begin
  if DoAbort then SysUtils.Abort;
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.DoLoading;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnLoading) then FOnLoading(Self);
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.HTTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
  CheckAbort;
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  inherited;
  DoAbort := True;
end;

procedure TLoadListThread.Execute;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    st := TStringList.Create;
    try
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        if Assigned(FOnLoading) then Synchronize(DoLoading);
        CheckAbort;
        HTTP.Get(FUrl, ms);
        ms.Position := 0;
        st.LoadFromStream(ms, TEncoding.UTF8);
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
      CheckAbort;
      // Do something with st
    finally
      st.Free;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm58.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StopLoadListThread;
  LListThread := TLoadListThread.Create(urlserver);
  LListThread.OnLoading := LoadListThreadLoading;
  LListThread.OnTerminate := LoadListThreadFinished;
  LListThread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm58.StopLoadListThread;
begin
  if Assigned(LListThread) then
  begin
    LListThread.OnLoading := nil;
    LListThread.OnTerminate := nil;
    LListThread.Terminate;
    LListThread.WaitFor;
    FreeAndNil(LListThread);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm58.LoadListThreadLoading(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Text := 'Loading...';
end;

procedure TForm58.LoadListThreadFinished(Sender: TObject);
var
  Thread: TThread;
begin
  Thread := TThread(Sender);

  if Thread.FatalException = nil then
    // Do something
  else
    // Do something else

  // if using 10.1 Berlin or earlier:
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          Thread.Free;
        end
      );
    end;
  ).Start;

  // if using 10.2 Tokyo or later:
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Thread.Free;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm58.CloseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm58.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  StopLoadListThread;
  // Do something
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```